# 8086 µProcessor | Proteus Simulation | 7 Segment & Stepper Motor

Tags: microprocessor

I am trying to silmulate the 7segment& stepper motor with 8086mp using proteus.Program compled succesfully but when iam running it schematic capture iam getting an error called  program load address is beyond the internal memory range which i couldn't understood.Kindly waiting for a quick answer.

Comment: What is the program load address? What is the internal memory range?

Comment: Looks like your program is too big for the memory.

Answer (score 1):

The 8086 [starts execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4004529/410847) at `0xFFFF:0000`, which is only 16 bytes before end of address space.

You as a developer are supposed to put a jump instruction there to point the program counter at the *actual* program start.

If the PC just continues incrementing, you get a wrap-around at `FFFF:0010`. The behaviour here differes between chip versions, the original 8086 wraps to `0000:0000`, while modern variants (80286 and up) would access memory beyond 1MB. See also "A20 gate".

In most cases using addresses bigger than `FFFF:000F` will be a bug. Don't do that.